# STM32F103C8Tx. 0 - включает PC13, 1 - выключает. Почему?

Tags: stm32, электроника

Всем привет. Почему через HAL, Atollic TrueStudio STM32 на плате STM32F103C8Tx при подаче питания `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);` - светодиод включается, а если `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);` - выключается. Китайская подделка? На статьях у людей по-другому - 0 - выкл., 1 - вкл.

Comment: Светодиод можно посадить на +3v, а можно на землю. В зависимости от этого он будет или включатся, или наоборот. Если на пине еденица +3v (грубо), то относительно земли +3, а относительно +3 - там ноль. Если на пине ноль (грубо), то относительно +3v там будет разница потенциалов по модулю равная 3 вольта. А когда станет +3v, то разница потенциалов станет ноль вольт.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ух, пока что сложновато для меня. Где можно дополнительно прочитать, что бы разжовано полностью было?

Comment: Если вы считаете что ответ полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос, можете поставить зелёную галочку. Если нет - оставьте коментарий, что бы было понятно что именно вам не нравится в ответах ниже.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, забыл, извиняюсь

Comment: Не страшно, вы же тут впервые)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы это понять, надо сначала выяснить, каким образом контроллер устанавливает на своём выводе высокий или низкий уровень. Имеются два способа: Push-pull и Open Drain.

**Push-Pull**

[image: Порт в режиме Push-Pull]

Прямоугольником показано внутреннее устройство контроллера. Стрелочка - место подключения напряжения питания (плюса), горизонтальная черта - точка подключения нулевого потенциала (минуса, земли, GND). Когда вы записываете в регистр этого порта единицу, замыкается верхний ключ, когда ноль - нижний ключ. Так на порту окажется высокий или низкий логические уровни.

Здесь важно понимать, что при подаче высокого уровня порт напрямую подключается к напряжению питания, а поэтому при подключении к порту какого-либо устройства (например, светодиода), важно рассчитать ток, так как при его превышении порт может сгореть. Максимально допустимый ток смотрите в документации на ваш контроллер.

**Open Drain**

[image: Open Drain]

В этом режиме в контроллере работает только один ключ, который подключает порт к земле. Высокий уровень устанавливается с помощью внешнего подтягивающего резистора (или иного устройства, как скоро увидим). Когда ключ замкнут, на порту устанавливается низкий логический уровень. Когда ключ разомкнут, устанавливается высокий уровень.

---

**Схемы подключения светодиодов**

[image: LED]

На левом рисунке используется режим Push-Pull. Когда вы устанавливаете логическую единицу (пишете `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);`), светодиод загорается. Когда устанавливаете 0, гаснет.

На правом рисунке используется режим Open Drain. Когда устанавливаете единицу, ключ разомкнут, ток через светодиод не течёт, светодиод не горит. Когда устанавливаете ноль, ключ замкнут, ток течёт, светодиод горит.

Сопротивление резистора нужно рассчитать исходя из требуемого тока потребления светодиода и внутреннего сопротивления светодиода. Ток не должен превышать максимальный ток порта, но если у вас получается превышение, используйте другой светодиод, или сделайте подключение с внешним транзистором.

**Подключение с внешним транзистором**

[image: Led-Mosfet]

Схем подключения через транзистор достаточно много. Приведём здесь схему с одним полевым транзистором. Затвор подключается к выводу микроконтроллера, а порт контроллера может быть настроен в любом режиме. Подаём высокий уровень - светодиод горит, подаём низкий уровень - не горит.